# GAE app.yaml: How to set env variable that contains periods?

Tags: google-app-engine, yaml, app-engine-flexible

I'm checking out GAE Managed VMs using app.yaml, as described here https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/managed-vms/java/configuring-your-app-with-app-yaml

When I do

```
env_variables:
  java.util.logging.config.file: 'WEB-INF/logging.properties'
```

I get exception

```
google.appengine.api.yaml_errors.EventError: Value 'java.util.logging.config.file' for key in EnvironmentVariables does not match expression '^(?:[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*)$'
```

Is there any way to specify custom `logging.properties` through app.yaml?

Comment: I still haven't found the answer, but gcloud-maven plugin sources turned out to be extremely useful: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcloud-maven-plugin/tree/master/src/main/java/com/google/appengine/gcloudapp
Kudos to gcloud team for sources!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
env_variables:
  JAVA_USER_OPTS: -Djava.util.logging.config.file=webapps/root/WEB-INF/logging.properties
```

The `env_variables` section in `app.yaml` is for setting environment variables. Dots are [not allowed](https://bash.cyberciti.biz/guide/Rules_for_Naming_variable_name) in their names, so the exception makes sense.

You are trying to set `java.util.logging.config.file`, which is a system property, not an environment variable. To set it you need to provide `-Djava.util.logging.config.file=<value>` argument when starting Java. GAE Flexible image provides `JAVA_USER_OPTS` environment variable to customise Java command line, so you can use it to customise JUL settings (as is now also recommended in the image [readme](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/jetty-runtime#providing-loggingproperties-via-the-web-application)).

Also, `WEB-INF/logging.properties` value didn't work for me as the current dir is `$JETTY_BASE`, not `$JETTY_BASE/webapps/root`.

Comment: Correction, note this
JETTY_ARGS: -Djava.util.logging.config.file=WEB-INF/logging.properties

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/jetty-runtime#providing-loggingproperties-via-the-web-application

Answer (score 1):

The other answer is no longer correct. The property name is now named JAVA_OPTS

Full 'secret' variable names here
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/jetty-runtime#providing-loggingproperties-via-the-web-application

This is the correct setting now:

```
env_variables:
  JAVA_OPTS: -Djava.util.logging.config.file=webapps/root/WEB-INF/logging.properties
```

Comment: Apparently this is also incorrect. See https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/jetty-runtime#providing-loggingproperties-via-the-web-application

Answer (score 1):

For the Generally Available Flexible Environment,  use this format.

```
env_variables:
  JETTY_ARGS: -Djava.util.logging.config.file=WEB-INF/logging.properties
```

See [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/jetty-runtime#providing-loggingproperties-via-the-web-application) .